# Combining Multiple SELECT and CREATE queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

In a PHP file I have multiple queries because I work with multiple tables, and with the data I get a   and display such data. These queries could be merged into one? If anyone knows how I want to tell me what the code is like:

```
SELECT * FROM compras ; 

SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE idcliente = '$row[idcliente]'

SELECT * FROM pedidos_ventas WHERE idcompra = '$row[idcompra]'

SELECT * FROM mercaderias WHERE idmerc = '$rowped[idmercaderia]' LIMIT 1



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientes` (
      `idcliente` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      `apellido` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      `domicilio` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      `telefono` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `movil` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `dni` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
      `familiar` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idcliente`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `compras` (
      `idcompra` INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `idcliente` INT(7) NOT NULL,
      `observacion` text NOT NULL,
      `fecha_ingreso` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idcompra`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entregas_ventas` (
      `identrega` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `idcompra` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      `entrega` DOUBLE(7,2) NOT NULL,
      `fecha` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`identrega`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mercaderias` (
      `idmerc` INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `cantidad` INT(5) NOT NULL,
      `codigo` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      `producto` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      `preciofinal` DOUBLE(7,2) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idmerc`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pedidos_ventas` (
      `idpedido` INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `idcompra` INT(7) NOT NULL,
      `idmercaderia` INT(7) NOT NULL,
      `kilo` DOUBLE(7,2) NOT NULL,
      `precio` DOUBLE(7,2) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idpedido`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

select compras.idcompra, case when clientes.idcliente is null 
         then 'ninguno' else CONCAT(clientes.nombre, ',', clientes.apellido)
    end as nombre, case when pedidos_ventas.idmercaderia = '-1' then 'Vianda saludable' when pedidos_ventas.idmercaderia = '-2' then 'Comida Sana'  else mercaderias.producto end as mercaderia,  pedidos_ventas.kilo, pedidos_ventas.precio  from compras 
    left join clientes  on (compras.idcliente=clientes.idcliente) 
    left join pedidos_ventas on (pedidos_ventas.idcompra=compras.idcompra) 
    left join mercaderias on (pedidos_ventas.idmercaderia=mercaderias.idmerc)  
    order by compras.idcompra asc
```

If now I would like to use the LIKE to see if it matches a value that I enter in an input $ _POST ['search'], either by customer name, vianda(lunch-box), food, or any merchandise ?? Try to do this and it does not work

```
SELECT compras.idcompra, CASE WHEN clientes.idcliente IS NULL 
     THEN 'ninguno' ELSE CONCAT(clientes.nombre, ',', clientes.apellido)
END AS nombre, CASE WHEN pedidos_ventas.idmercaderia = '-1' THEN 'Vianda saludable' WHEN pedidos_ventas.idmercaderia = '-2' THEN 'Comida Sana'  ELSE mercaderias.producto END AS mercaderia,  pedidos_ventas.kilo, pedidos_ventas.precio  FROM compras 
LEFT JOIN clientes  ON (compras.idcliente=clientes.idcliente) 
LEFT JOIN pedidos_ventas ON (pedidos_ventas.idcompra=compras.idcompra) 
LEFT JOIN mercaderias ON (pedidos_ventas.idmercaderia=mercaderias.idmerc)  WHERE mercaderias.producto LIKE '%comida%' OR..... LIKE clientes... or LIKE ..
ORDER BY compras.idcompra ASC
```

Comment: Are the result sets related in some way?

Comment: Yes you can combine it.  However if you don't have proper Primary Key -> Foreign Key relationships it can SLOW down bad

Comment: Hard to say not knowing the structure of your tables and relation between them.

Comment: It's also hard to say without seeing how these loops are nested and the results displayed.

Comment: View https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42047/because-datatables-do-not-filter-the-data-when-searching#latest

Comment: @NobleUplift How do I use the like by name, merchandise, products?

Answer (score 0):

For a query with your current schema, try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM compras
INNER JOIN clientes ON (compras.idcliente = clientes.idcliente) 
INNER JOIN pedidos_ventas ON (compras.id = pedidos_venta.id) 
INNER JOIN mercaderias ON (pedidos_ventas.idmercaderia = mercaderias.idmerc) 
WHERE clientes.idcliente = :clienteid
AND compras.idcompra = :compraid 
AND mercaderias.idmerc = :mercaderiaid
```

**IDEAL DATABASE DESIGN**

Try adding foreign keys to your schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cliente` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `domicilio` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `movil` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dni` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `familiar` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mercaderia` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cantidad` INT(5) NOT NULL,
  `codigo` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `producto` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `preciofinal` DOUBLE(7,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `compra` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cliente_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `observacion` text NOT NULL,
  `fecha_ingreso` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_compra_cliente`
      FOREIGN KEY (`cliente_id`)
      REFERENCES `cliente` (`id`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entregas_venta` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `compra_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `entrega` DOUBLE(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_entregas_venta_compra`
      FOREIGN KEY (`compra_id`)
      REFERENCES `compra` (`id`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pedidos_venta` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `compra_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `mercaderia_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `kilo` DOUBLE(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `precio` DOUBLE(7,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pedidos_venta_compra`
      FOREIGN KEY (`compra_id`)
      REFERENCES `compra` (`id`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pedidos_venta_mercaderia`
      FOREIGN KEY (`mercaderia_id`)
      REFERENCES `mercaderia` (`id`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And then use the query:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(<<<SQL
    SELECT * FROM compra
    INNER JOIN cliente ON (compra.cliente_id = cliente.id) 
    INNER JOIN pedidos_venta ON (compra.id = pedidos_venta.id) 
    INNER JOIN mercaderia ON (pedidos_venta.mercaderia_id = mercaderia.id) 
    WHERE cliente.id = :clienteid
    AND compra.id = :compraid 
    AND mercaderia.id = :mercaderiaid
SQL
);
$stmt->execute(':clienteid' => $clienteid, ':compraid' => $compraid, ':mercaderiaid' => $mercaderiaid);
```

Comment: I think you're making a LOT of assumptions about OP's data. There is absolutely no way to verify this answer

Comment: There are a few times where I've had to use `CROSS JOIN`s for my application. Only way to know is to keep the discussion going.

Comment: I suspect his intent is that `$row` is each row of results from the `compras` query, and `$rowped` is each row from the `pedidos_ventas` query. So he's looking for something that joins all these tables, not a cross join.

Comment: But we need to see how his original code is structured to know specifically. I suspect it will have to be two joins, one that joins `compras` with `clientes`, and another that joins `compras`, `pedidos_ventas`, and `mercaderias`.

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42047/because-datatables-do-not-filter-the-data-when-searching#latest

Comment: @FernandoRossi, I've updated my answer with schema changes to account for foreign keys, and a query you should be able to use in a prepared statement. I also changed your table names to use singular case, just like in your data tables link.

Comment: @FernandoRossi, try the query that I added into the top of my answer, based off your current query.

Comment: @NobleUplift help please Read what I wrote above

Comment: @FernandoRossi What do you mean wrote above?